# Symfony 4.1 - Two EntityManagers. Migration goes twice on second EntityManager

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've followed the directions on this page:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

And my doctrine.yaml file looks like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: one
        connections:
            one:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_ONE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            two:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(DATABASE_TWO_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: one
        entity_managers:
            one:
                connection: one
                mappings:
                    One:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/One'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\One'
                        alias: One
            two:
                connection: two
                mappings:
                    Two:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Two'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Two'
                        alias: Two
```

I've got a One and Two directory inside my Entity directory with a simple Entity class in both:

A **Person** in **One**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\One;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    {Getters and setters ...}
}
```

A **Post** in **Two**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Two;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $title;


    {Getters and setters ...}
}
```

When I run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` and `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate` the **Person** is added to the **One** database correctly.

When I run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --em=two` and `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em=two` both this and the **Person** migration for **One** are executed and the **Two** database has both a **Person** and a **Page** table.

I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong with this